# How to initialize libraries by their string names in cluster?

Tags: r, substitution, snowfall

I want to initialize libraries in cluster by their names represented as strings.

This code works fine:

```
library(snowfall, rlecuyer, rsprng)
sfInit(parallel = TRUE, cpus = 4, type = "SOCK")
sfClusterEval(library(e1071))
```

And this code produces en error: `4 nodes produced errors; first error: object 'expr' not found`

```
library(snowfall, rlecuyer, rsprng)
sfInit(parallel = TRUE, cpus = 4, type = "SOCK")
lib <- "e1071"
expr <- parse(text=paste("library(", lib, ")", sep=""))
sfClusterEval(expr)
```

So `sfClusterEval` try to evaluate `expr` and not an expression which `expr` contains. I cannot undestand which type of expression should be passed to `sfClusterEval` function, which uses `substitute` in its body

```
> sfClusterEval
function (expr, stopOnError = TRUE) 
{
    sfCheck()
    if (sfParallel()) {
        return(sfClusterCall(eval, substitute(expr), env = globalenv(), 
            stopOnError = stopOnError))
    }
    else {
        return(eval(expr, envir = globalenv(), enclos = parent.frame()))
    }
}
```

This question seems simple, but I could not solve it and need someone's advice.

**UPDATE:**

Further investigation details on simplier examples. I feel that the truth is near.
This code works fine

```
sfClusterEval(library("e1071"))
```

But this call produces en error: 4 nodes produced errors; first error: object 'lib' not found

```
lib <- "e1071"
sfClusterEval(library(lib, character.only=TRUE))
```

**ANSWER:**

The variable `lib` should be exported to the cluster previously. And after that it can be removed.

```
lib <- "e1071"
sfExport("lib")
sfClusterEval(library(lib, character.only=TRUE))
sfRemove("lib")
```

Thanks for Richie, for giving the starting idea!

Comment: Why don't you use `sfLibrary` to load the packages into workers?

Comment: Excelent advice! I missed this feature of the snowfall package. Shame on me. :) If you will post this comment as a answer, I'll be able to mark it as a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `sfLibrary` to load extra packages on workers. See `?snowfall` and click `snowfall-tools`.

Answer (score 1):

Whether in a cluster or not, you simply use the `character.only` argument to `library`.

```
library("e1071", character.only = TRUE)
```

---

If your nodes report an error stating that they can't find the package, double check that the package is installed on that machine, in a location that is one of `.libPaths()`.  If all else fails, explicitly provide the location of the package in the `lib.loc` argument to `library`.

Comment: Hm... It seems that such approach doesn't work in this situation. See the update to the answer. Where am I wrong?

Comment: @DrDom: Updated with how to find the package.

Comment: It was even simplier, variable `lib` was absent in the cluster nodes and thus it was invisble to them. And as I understand evaluation of the function performs on each node separately. Yes, it's logical, I know. But nevertheless, many thanks to you for giving me a right direction!

Comment: Glad you've solved it.  If the answer was useful to you, remember to click the up arrow to vote.

Comment: You might also consider moving your solution to it's own answer (you can answer your own question), then clicking the tick to mark it as solved.